# Native DLL not being published to Azure Compute Emulator

Tags: dll, azure, native

I have a native DLL (x64) built with VC++ 2008 that I'm trying to use in an azure project. The code runs fine in a standalone executable, but when I try to run it in the Compute Emulator, I receive a DLL not found exception.

For several days I've been assuming the issue is with the VC++ redistributables not being present, but [that shouldn't be an issue with dll's built using VS 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh694038.aspx).

Using ProcMon, I discovered something odd -- the DLL is not being found anywhere on the path. Further poking around showed that the DLL is not being copied to the approot folder, despite the fact that it is set to Build Action = none + Copy Always.

I manually copied the DLL to the Compute Emulator's path in the SDK and now it runs. But why does VS not copy the DLL along with my project files into the approot when I press F5?